# Creating Key Value Array From Existing Array (With Substr)

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying to setup an array with a key and value, but can't seem to get my code working right. An example of my array is as follows...

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "Dry Traction 4 out of 5"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "Wet Traction 4 out of 5"
  [2]=>
  string(34) "Steering Responsiveness 4 out of 5"
  [3]=>
  string(22) "Noise Level 3 out of 5"
}
```

With this array, I'm using substr() to seperate the numbers (the last 10 characters), but would like the first part of the string to become the key. My substr code is as follows...

```
foreach($array as $item) {
  $value = substr($item, -10);
}
```

I feel terrible for asking as I wanted to figure this out on my own, but I really appreciate any and all help!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't generally like keys with spaces in it but this will do what you want

```
$array = array();
foreach($array as $item) {
  $key   = trim(substr($item, 0, strlen($item) - 10));
  $value = substr($item, -10);
  $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VL8NJ2)

I just use `substr()` twice. The first one also uses `strlen()` to help determine where to end our substring and `trim()` to get rid of whitespace. The second is identical to your code to get the numerical portion of the string. I then just put it into an array with the former as the key and the latter at the value.

Answer (score 0):

John's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23621305/1003917) will do , You can also do using an `array_walk()`

```
$new_arr = array(); //<--- Your new array which is going to be modified
array_walk($yourarray,function (&$v,$k) use($new_arr) {
    $new_arr[trim(substr($v,0,-10))] = substr($v,-10);
} );
print_r($new_arr);
```